# How to sort a list of text+date strings in Groovy

Tags: sorting, groovy

I have a list of strings, each one contains text with date like this:

```
"foo_6.7.2016"
"foo_5.10.2016"
"foo_6.30.2016"
"foo_6.23.2016"
"foo_6.2.2016"
"foo_5.22.2016"
```

I need to sort them by Date and get this:

```
"foo_6.30.2016"
"foo_6.23.2016"
"foo_6.7.2016"
"foo_6.2.2016"
"foo_5.22.2016"
"foo_5.10.2016"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative might be:

```
def foos = [ 
    "foo_6.7.2016",
    "foo_5.10.2016",
    "foo_6.30.2016",
    "foo_6.23.2016",
    "foo_6.2.2016",
    "foo_5.22.2016"
]

def sorted = foos.sort(false) { Date.parse('M.d.yyyy', it - 'foo_') }.reverse()
```

Comment: Nice - definitely a more groovy way than my approach

Comment: Your way has the advantage that you only parse the dates once

Comment: If one used the spaceship operator... f(b) <=> f(a) then reverse() could go away? Assuming f is the closure specified in this answer.

Comment: Excellent. Timely help.

Answer (score 4):

For a quick answer that needs substantial cleanup:

```
def dates = [
"foo_6.7.2016"
"foo_5.10.2016"
"foo_6.30.2016"
"foo_6.23.2016"
"foo_6.2.2016"
"foo_5.22.2016"
]

def prefix = "foo_"
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("M.d.yyyy")
def sorted_dates = dates.collect{ sdf.parse(
    it, new java.text.ParsePosition(prefix.length()) ) }.sort().reverse()
def newDates = sorted_dates.collect{ "${prefix} + ${sdf.format(it)}"}
println newDates
```